# treble for loop using R foreach

Tags: r, parallel-foreach

I tried to use the parallel R package `foreach` for a treble for loop. `out` should be an 3-d array and I keep getting a 2-d matrix. A simple example:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

aa <-  seq(1,10, length=4)
bb <- seq(0,1, length=4)
cc <- seq(0,1, length=4)

fun <- function(a,b,c){return(a+b-c)}
out <- array(NaN, dim=c(4,4,4))

registerDoParallel()
out <- foreach(i = aa, .combine='cbind', .multicombine=TRUE) %dopar% {
  foreach(j = bb, .combine='cbind', .multicombine=TRUE) %:%
    foreach(k = cc, .combine='c') %dopar% { fun(i, j,k) }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `cbind` is combining the matrices column-wise into a larger matrix.  What you need is a function that combines matrices into 3-D arrays, such as the `abind` function from the `abind` package.  Since it needs an extra argument, I define the combine function as:

```
mbind <- function(...) abind(..., along=3)
```

Here's how I would use it for your example:

```
library(abind)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel()
aa <- seq(1,10, length=4)
bb <- seq(0,1, length=4)
cc <- seq(0,1, length=4)

fun <- function(a,b,c) {return(a+b-c)}
mbind <- function(...) abind(..., along=3)

out <-
  foreach(i=aa, .combine='mbind', .multicombine=TRUE) %:%
    foreach(j=bb, .combine='cbind') %:%
      foreach(k=cc, .combine='c') %dopar% {
        fun(i, j, k)
      }
```

On Linux and Mac OS X, this entire nested loop will be turned into a single call to `mclapply`.  If combining the results takes too much time, it may be better to only parallelize the outer loop, as suggested by mrip, so that the workers perform much of the combining.

Comment: Extending your answer to a quadruple loop isn't so obvious, or perhaps I'm just being slow. If you /anyone else could help out again I'll be grateful

Answer (score 1):

You have all the right data, you just need to change the dimensions:

```
dim(out)<-c(4,4,4)
```

If you want the dimensions to be such that `out[i,j,k] == fun(aa[i],bb[k],cc[k])` then you need to permute them like this:

```
out<-aperm(out,c(3,2,1))
```

This can be verified:

```
out2<-array(0,dim(out))
for(i in 1:4)
  for(j in 1:4)
    for(k in 1:4)
      out2[i,j,k]<-fun(aa[i],bb[j],cc[k])

identical(out,out2)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps! Any tips on the foreach function will also be great too! Either way, your answer is helpful!

Comment: You probably don't need the `%dopar%` in the third loop.  Try with `%do%` instead, it might be faster.  Usually, it is better to parallelize as coarsely as possible, so that you spend less time splitting tasks up among threads and more time actually doing the work.